# vue.js and slot in attribute

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to build a vue.js template that implements following:

- `<MyComponent></MyComponent>` generates `<div class="a"></div>`
- `<MyComponent>b</MyComponent>` generates `<div class="a" data-text="b"></div>`.

Is such a thing possible?

**EDIT**

Here is the best I can reach:

```
  props: {
    text: {
      type: [Boolean, String],
      default: false
    }
  },
```

and template

```
<template>
  <div :class="classes()" :data-text="text">
    <slot v-bind:text="text"></slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

but the binding does not work, `text` always contains `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `mounted()` method to get text using `$slot.default` property of the component to get the enclosing text. Create a text field in data and update inside `mounted()` method like this :

```
Vue.component('mycomponent', {
  data: () => ({
    text: ""
  }),
  template: '<div class="a" :data-text=text></div>',
  mounted(){
    let slot = this.$slots.default[0];
    this.text=slot.text;

  }
});
```

Note: It will only work for text, not for Html tags or components.

Comment: wow, thank you. I had to add an additional method because in case the slot is empty, the data-text has to be hidden

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing slots and properties here. You'll have to pass whatever you want to end up as your `data-text` attribute as a prop to your component.

```
<MyComponent text="'b'"></MyComponent>
```

And in your template you can remove the slot

```
<template>
    <div :class="classes()" :data-text="text"></div>
</template>
```

Another thing: it looks like your binding your classes via a method. This could be done via computed properties, take a look if you're not familiar.

Comment: Thank you for the hint about computed props. About the solution: I would like to preserve my syntax, that is the syntax is given and the question is: is it possible to have a template implementing the given syntax? +1

Comment: That's not really what slots are made for, though, and I don't know of a way to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
<template>
  <div :class="classes()">
    <slot name="body" v-bind:text="text" v-if="hasDefaultSlot">
    </slot>
  </div>
</template>


computed: {
    hasDefaultSlot() {
        console.log(this)
        return this.$scopedSlots.hasOwnProperty("body");
    },
}


Calling

<MyComponent>
<template v-slot:body="props">
b
</template>
</MyComponent>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this solution is too far away from the syntax of the specification. The user of the component has to write to much and remember a too complex syntax.